# How to setup multiple (isolated) Magento admin views (multi-vendor)

Tags: configuration, multistore, magento-1.7, multi-vendor

I am using `magento 1.7`. I want to use same Magento installation for multiple separate vendors.

I have set up multiple store views for the fronted (for each respective domain) but I have been unable to set up the Magento admin in the same fashion - where each domain administrator/vendor can add categories, products etc. ***only*** for his domain site

Comment: Your may use  magento multi vendor marketplace https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-Marketplace.html which will surely help for your needs

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to be able to set up multiple admin views - you need the ability for vendors to submit products to the catalog (with your final approval, of course), fulfill orders, print shipping labels, etc.

In that case what you really need is a dropship solution. I'm very familiar with and constantly impressed by the range of products by Unirgy. I use them very often with a number of clients, especially uDropship. Sure, it's an expensive 'plugin' but it'd be much more expensive for you or a team of developers to spend weeks or months reinventing this wheel.

http://www.unirgy.com/

Comment: +1 for Unirgy Drop Ship. Amazingly deep extension that already does what you're looking for. I disagree that it is "expensive", however. Its cost is well within reason for the amount of money it saves you in development costs.

Comment: Expensive in the terms of it not being an average $79 extension. I agree that it a small amount of money for the rich feature set

Answer (score 3):

Magento Enterprise Edition generally does a reasonably good job of allowing different admins with limited access to their own stores, if that's a viable option within your budget.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for exactly? A way to separate the Magento admin into separate stores? Magento's native ACL do not facilitate this.

Magento can have many store views to one admin, but not many *admin views* to many stores.

There have been a few attempts at granular store-view level ACLs by 3rd party extension manufacturers to achieve this. So you could look at those.

We've faced this challenge in the past for customers who wanted to white-label their store. As a result, we have used one of two methods.

1. Set up many separate stores, with separate installations - then feed the sales data back to a central installation
2. Implement admin store-level ACLs.

Either way, its not that easy. Magento wasn't strictly designed for this purpose.

Comment: yes you are right i am looking multiple admin views

Comment: is theire any way to setup this

Comment: That's all the information I can sensibly provide. Actually telling you *how to do it* is **way** beyond the scope of the question. If you don't have a firm enough grasp of Magento to do this yourself - I'm afraid its out-of-reach for you and you're likely using the wrong product; it doesn't natively do what you want it to do.

Comment: so can you please suggess me any other product for acheive this i means any other cms or any other cart

Comment: or do  you know any good tutorial for aceive this