# Enable certain users to add products to my store

Tags: product, extensions, frontend, products-management

I'd like to allow some users to sell products in my store, without giving them access to magento's back end.

Is there any extension for doing that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is commonly known as an [online marketplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_marketplace). There are a number of extensions that do this, the most popular of which by far is [Unirgy Dropship](https://secure.unirgy.com//products/udropship/). It is an expensive, commercial, solution.

This has been covered a few times here before:

[How to setup multiple (isolated) Magento admin views (multi-vendor)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/how-to-setup-multiple-isolated-magento-admin-views-multi-vendor)

[Etsy style multi vendor site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/etsy-style-multi-vendor-site)

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of commercial extension available to add similar functionality (search for "Customer as a partner"). I've seen at least two of such extensions, but there could be more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a freebie, I just installed this one.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-marketplace.html